# Is there a way to define a 'heterogeneous' kernel design to incorporate linear operators into the regression for GPflow (or GPytorch/GPy/...)?

Tags: python, regression, gpflow, gaussian-process, gpytorch

I'm trying to perform a GP regression with linear operators as described in for example this paper by Särkkä: [https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/pub/spde.pdf](https://users.aalto.fi/%7Essarkka/pub/spde.pdf) In this example we can see from equation (8) that I need a **different kernel function** for the **four covariance blocks** (of training and test data) in the complete covariance matrix.

This is definitely possible and valid, but I would like to include this in a **kernel definition** of (preferably) GPflow, or GPytorch, GPy or the like.

However, in the **documentation** for **kernel design** in [Gpflow](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/tailor/kernel_design.html), the only possibility is to  define a covariance **function** that **acts on *all* covariance blocks**. In principle, the method above should be straight-forward to add myself (the kernel function expressions can be derived analytically), but I don't see any way of **incorporating** the '**heterogeneous' kernel functions** into the regression or kernel classes. I tried to consult other packages such as [Gpytorch](https://docs.gpytorch.ai/en/latest/kernels.html#kernel) and [Gpy](https://gpy.readthedocs.io/en/deploy/tuto_creating_new_kernels.html), but again, the kernel design does not seem to allow this.

Maybe I'm missing something here, maybe I'm not familiar enough with the underlying implementation to asses this, but if someone has done this before or sees the (what should be reasonably straight-forward?) implementation possibility, I would be happy to find out.

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be reasonably straightforward, though requires building a custom kernel. Basically, you need a kernel that can know for each input what the linear operator for the corresponding output is (whether this is a function observation/identity operator, integral observation, derivative observation, etc). You can achieve this by including an extra column in your input matrix `X`, similar to how it's done for the `gpflow.kernels.Coregion` kernel (see [this notebook](https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/master/notebooks/advanced/coregionalisation.html)). You would need to then need to define a new kernel with `K` and `K_diag` methods that for each linear operator type find the corresponding rows in the input matrix, and pass it to the appropriate covariance function (using `tf.dynamic_partition` and `tf.dynamic_stitch`, this is used in a very similar way in GPflow's [`SwitchedLikelihood` class](https://github.com/GPflow/GPflow/blob/282d1cdd1cea79702aeced3781239e79c2197f7c/gpflow/likelihoods/base.py#L510)).

The full implementation would probably take half a day or so, which is beyond what I can do here, but I hope this is a useful starting pointer, and you're very welcome to join the GPflow slack (invite link in the GPflow README) and discuss it in more detail there!

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question!
It seems that indeed, including the natural cross-covariance terms that arise when dealing with linear operators can also be taken care of in a direct way. If I'm not mistaken, this approach should also work when (for example) only observing derivative and/or integral data, since the 'type' of test data (the original latent function) is passed to the kernel in the prediction step as well.
This was exactly the type of starting point I was looking for! Also, those are some very relevant TF methods, so thanks once again!